# Keep ATI (fglrx) and NVidia (nvidia-current) Drivers on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on external disk and 2 computers with ATI and NVidia driver each. Actually I'm using nvidia proprietary as main driver and did not install ATI driver. But after upgrade a day ago, unity just showing some weird stuff, i can't describe here by text but it's looks like just a few shape or triangle in unity launcher and top menu. It's kinda like a game need some 3d acceleration and showing only it's spirits.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: So what the hell is the question?

Comment: "But after upgrade a day ago, unity just showing some weird stuff, i can't describe here by text but it's looks like just a few shape or triangle in unity launcher and top menu. It's kinda like a game need some 3d acceleration and showing only it's spirits." The answer is "it's just a bug from xorg ppa's" thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the question is: "Is it possible?"

...and I hope it really is... ok, it's not ubuntu, but the opportunity is there:

"The AMD catalyst driver can be installed as usual (I'm still using the catalyst-total AUR package).
All you need to do is manually install the NVIDIA driver (available from their website) using the
 "--no-opengl-files option."

I read it here:
 [Running both an AMD and an NVIDIA GPU possible?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179549)